# How do I get sub string from string

Tags: c#

How do I get sub string if a string contains the following characters "Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :" followed by  any string?

Ex:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : abc.abc.com
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8ca3:bc6c:d958:f1f5%13
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.96.72.154
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.96.72.1

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : abc.abc.com

Tunnel adapter isatap.asia.jci.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : abc.abc.com

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter isatap.{DB074F38-9E68-4ABE-AF31-D3750FE10DE1}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter isatap.{01405796-6937-431A-B61D-DBC785F4F56B}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

i want only **Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : abc.abc.com** string from hole string

Comment: Is the DNS address terminated by a newline?

Comment: yes DNS address terminated by a newline

Answer (score 4):

So the text contains multiple lines and you want the whole line?

```
string result = allLines.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
  .FirstOrDefault(l=> l.TrimStart().StartsWith("Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :"));
```

it's `null` if it was not found.

```
if(result != null) result = result.Trim();
```

If it doesn't contain multiple lines and you want to find it in the middle of the string:

```
string result = null;
string textToFind = "Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :";
int startIndex = text.IndexOf(textToFind);
if (startIndex >= 0)
{ 
    string behind = text.Substring(startIndex + textToFind.Length).TrimStart();
    int endIndex = behind.IndexOf(" ");
    if (endIndex >= 0)
        behind = behind.Substring(0, endIndex).TrimEnd();
    result = string.Format("{0} {1}", textToFind, behind);
}
```

Note that string comparisons are case sensitive in .NET by default. If you want to ignore the case (so that `Connection` and `connection` are treated the same) you can use the overload of [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes a `StringComparison`, for example:

```
int startIndex = text.IndexOf(textToFind, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int startIndex = s.IndexOf("Connection-specific DNS Suffix", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
string substring  = s.Substring(startIndex, s.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, startIndex) - startIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

it will work in all the situations

```
 string your_string = "tomany_words_Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :abcd.comLinkbfdbfdb";
        string check_string="Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :";
        int index;
        int last_index;
        string final;
        if (true == your_string.Contains(check_string))
        {
            index=your_string.IndexOf(check_string);
            last_index = your_string.IndexOf("Link");

            final = your_string.Substring(index + check_string.Length, last_index - (index + check_string.Length));              
            Console.WriteLine(final);
        }
```